# Way to short-circuit propogation of checked exception in JUnit

Tags: java, exception, junit

I just thought of something minor I would like to do and was curious if it the ability to do it existed.  It's purely a convenience syntactic-sugar sort of thing, hardly mandatory to have, but a slight convenience I thought may have been implemented at some point.

I have a method nestled 2-3 layers down in helper methods of a Junit test case which throws a checked exception.  I know for a fact that I want to fail if this exception is ever thrown.  However, if I just call Fail() I lose the stack trace of the exception and the other conveniences that come with allowing the exception to propagate

I know the 'standard' approach is to have the method throw the exception.  However, as I said, I'm buried  a few methods deep already, and I suspect this method will be called by many future helper methods.  If I throw an exception in this method I will have to constantly adding a throw clause to all the methods that use this one method, directly or indirectly, which could be quite a few methods.  This is obviously doable, just a little annoying; and, in theory at least, I could mask a situation where the exception is thrown and I actually wanted to catch it if all my methods already throw it.

Is there a way I can tell JUnit to act as if the exception *had* propagated up to the top level and fail, without having to have all my methods throw it?  So JUnit reports a failure due to exception, with the stack trace and all, immediately.  Essentially I want a fail method that takes an exception.

Does anything like this exist, or do I have to simply throw it?

ps. I know I could wrap it in a RuntimeException and re-throw it, but I don't really like that option either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard function I create in a test utility class that creates and throws an AssertionError (which is what the [Fail method of jUnit does](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assert.java#L84): )

```
// this is from the JUnit source code 
static public void fail(String message) {
    if (message == null) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    throw new AssertionError(message);
}
```

So, I have a standard utility method in my test harness which does:

```
static public void fail(String message, Throwable t) {
    if (message == null) {
        throw new AssertionError(t);
    }
    throw new AssertionError(message, t);
}
```

And then the actual exception is available on the fail method......

from your low-level test you just do

```
MyTestUtilClass.fail("This exception was thrown", e);
```

The process works really well. and you get a standard fail exit, but also the details of the cause exception (visible on commandline and thinks like the eclipse JUnit interface)